# Windrose (Barpolar) in Dash is not updating

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I want to implement a windrose (with Dash) for displaying the direction of wind data. I am using a callback function and the idea is that the data is displayed for different times -  for this I am using a slider, where the time can be selected. The problem here is that after selecting the time, I have to double click on the windrose so that it is updated and displays the data.

I used the same code with a normal line plot, and there it worked fine (meaning that it updated right away without double clicking).

Thanks in advance!

```py
# visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in your web browser.

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import logging

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('..\\..\\data\\raw\\fake_wind.csv', # 
    index_col=0,        
    parse_dates=True) # finds dates "automatically"
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # convert argument to datetime


 

# Initialize the app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
# app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True # ??

 

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1("Wind Direction"),
        dcc.Slider(id='windrose',
            min=1,#min(df.index),
            max=5,#max(df.index),
            value=5,
            marks={
                0: '0 °F',
                3: '3 °F',
                5: '5 °F',
                7.65: '7.65 °F',
                10: '10 °F'

            }

        ),  
        html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
        #html.Br(),

        #dcc.Graph(id='sun_map', figure={})
        dcc.Graph(id='wind_map2', config={'displayModeBar': False}, animate=True)


])

import numpy as np
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output(component_id='wind_map2', component_property='figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('windrose', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    #fig=make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, specs=[[{'type': 'polar'}]*2]*2)
    row = df.iloc[value,:]

    barplot = go.Barpolar(
            r = [np.random.randint(1,10)],
            width=[10],
            theta = [np.random.randint(1,360)],
            marker_color=["#E4FF87", '#709BFF', '#709BFF', '#FFAA70', '#FFAA70', '#FFDF70', '#B6FFB4'],
            marker_line_color="black",
            marker_line_width=2,
            opacity=0.8
        )


    fig = go.Figure(data=barplot)

    return fig

    #return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)



    
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(title="time"),
        template='plotly_dark',
        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        #yaxis="W/s^2",
        #yaxis2=dict(title="Celsius",
        #overlaying='y',
        #side='right'),
        font=dict(
            family="Courier New, monospace",
            size=18,
            color="RebeccaPurple"
        )
    )
    return fig




# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True) # "hot-reloading" (Dash automatically refreshes browser when changes)
```

Comment: Your callback is returning the figure twice at the top level. The second return should be unreachable. Is this a formatting error in your post?

Comment: Yes, that was a formatting error, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

might be a bit late to answer. However I think you should change the "updatemode " in your slider from 'mouseup' to drag. As per the docs here https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider

> updatemode (a value equal to: 'mouseup', 'drag'; default 'mouseup'):
> Determines when the component should update its value property. If
> mouseup (the default) then the slider will only trigger its value when
> the user has finished dragging the slider. If drag, then the slider
> will update its value continuously as it is being dragged. If you want
> different actions during and after drag, leave updatemode as mouseup
> and use drag_value for the continuously updating value.